# MailKit - how to correctly create message body with German text with BodyBuilder

Tags: mailkit

I would like to create message body with German text with the help of the BodyBuilder.

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder();
builder.TextBody = "ÄÄÄÄÄ"; 
mimeMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

The received message has the text: ÃÃÃÃÃ

Is it possible to use BodyBuilder in that case?

I have tried too

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder();
var utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8,Encoding.Default.GetBytes("ÄÄÄÄÄ"));
builder.TextBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes); 
mimeMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

with the same result.

Comment: I use MailKit 1.18.1 with VS 2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: How are you sending the message? Is this with .NET Core or standard .NET 4.x? Are you sure that the receiving client is properly handling charsets?

Comment: Are you using `MimeMessage.ToString()` to get the "raw" message data? If so, don't. Use WriteTo(). That solves 100% of all "charset issues" that people have reported over the years. The ToString() method is meant for debugging purposes only and is not meant to be used for getting the raw message text.

Comment: MimeMessage.ToString() was exactly my problem! WriteTo() solved my problem. Many thanks!